# ruby cant install gems, only manually

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Title says it all, whenever I try to install a gem this happens :

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'ruby2d' (>= 0), here is why: 
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I have reinstalled ruby to try to fix this, without any luck.
Also, I tried updating my rubygems version, getting this error :

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/julia_ps3fg4w/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby25-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/julia_ps3fg4w/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - C:/Users/julia_ps3fg4w/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
```

Comment: Check that `rubygems.org` resolves, and that you can connect to it. You may have firewall restrictions preventing this from working.

Comment: can connect to rubygems.org, downloading my gems from there to manually install them, however that is quite tedious.
edit : 
how would i go about seeing if i have those firewall restrictions ? (using win10)

Comment: enter this in terminal and post output: `gem env`

Comment: edited. @lacostenycoder

Comment: Are you using Cygwin or Bash on Ubuntu on Windows ?  You probably should be. I also recommend using a ruby version manager see https://rvm.io/rvm/install but try answer I've posted first.

Comment: had smth similar when i had paths with spaces in my system path environment variable, not saying it's the cause here but use the short form of the paths in windows

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing sources in your gem configuration. Try this.

```
gem sources -a  http://rubygems.org
```

It should edit your `~/.gemrc` file to look like this:

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- http://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

Comment: didnt fix the issue, however i did mange to fix it... seems like a stupid issue on rubegems.org side.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2253

TL;DR: some ipv6 requests dont go through. use ipv4

Answer (score 0):

I faced also the same problem on my Mac OS 13 Venture.

1. I changed my IpV6 configuration like this

[image: IPv6 configuration settings]

3. Restarted my MAC.
4. Then `gem install bundler`